# How to set position absolute only in x direction.

Tags: html, css

Say that I have the bellow fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/4896/

As you can see as soon as I set a height on the table div it doesn't apply to the left columns since they have position absolute and I cant do a overflow on that class either since each column element has that class. So how would you solve this issue? I want the left column to have the same Y scrollbar as the table to the right. The obvious answer would be to split up the table into 2 tables, but then I would like the two x scrollbars to be linked together somehow so that when I scroll one table in the x direction then the other table is also scrolled and vice versa.

[image]

```
div { 
    width: 600px; 
    overflow-x:scroll;  
    height: 300px;     
    margin-left:5em; 
    overflow-y:visible;
    padding-bottom:1px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer using jQuery. See fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/YMvk9/4900/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.headcol').css('left',$(window).scrollLeft()+'px');
    console.log("scroll");
});
```